# How to set the style of the first/last item of QListWidget?

Tags: c++, qt, qtstylesheets

I want to implement the following effect in a *QListWidget*:

[image]

Unfortunatelly, there is no `QListWidget::item:first` in the stylesheet of *QListWidget*.

Ist there something like `css`'s brother selector `li~li` in `qss`?

I have examined the [Qt Style example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html), but the info there is not sufficient for me.

Comment: Can you explain, what you want to achieve? I see a list with consecutive numbers, that should be easy!?

Comment: @Jens I want to achieve each item has `border-top:2px solid` exclude the first item.

Comment: I see - that was the point. Qt styles are very limited indeed, so scopchanov's way must be correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Cause

*QListView*, resp. *QListWidget* indeed does not support `::item:first`, so you are not able to achieve what you want with the use of stylesheets.

## Solution

You can use a delegate instead. Subclass [QStyledItemDelegate](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyleditemdelegate.html), reimplement [QAbstractItemDelegate::paint](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemdelegate.html#paint) and [QAbstractItemDelegate::sizeHint](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemdelegate.html#sizeHint) and adjust them to your liking.

## Example

Here is an example of how this solution could be implemented:

1. Create a class `Delegate : public QStyledItemDelegate`

In *Delegate.cpp*:

```
void Delegate::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    int b = option.rect.bottom() - 1;

    painter->save();
    painter->setClipping(true);
    painter->setClipRect(option.rect);

    if (index.row() < index.model()->rowCount() - 1)
        painter->drawLine(option.rect.left() + 5, b, option.rect.right() - 5, b);

    painter->restore();

    QStyledItemDelegate::paint(painter, option, index);
}

QSize Delegate::sizeHint(const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    QSize sz(QStyledItemDelegate::sizeHint(option, index));

    sz.setHeight(32);

    return sz;
}
```

2. Test the class in a Qt widgets application

In *MainWindow.cpp*:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent)
{
    auto *list = new QListWidget(this);

    list->addItems(QStringList{"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"});
    list->setItemDelegate(new Delegate(this));
    list->setFrameStyle(QFrame::NoFrame);

    setCentralWidget(list);
    setContentsMargins(9, 9, 9, 9);
    resize(200, 300);
}
```

## Result

The provided example produces the following result:

[image: Window with QListWidget containing 6 items separated by a line]

Comment: @Shun, if you like the answer, you might also consider upvoting it.

Comment: it seems must add some border style to `QListWidget::Item` that can see effect. I add `border-top:0px`.Also, when select item, the item text will be disappeared.

Comment: @Shun, if you use delegate, do not set Stylesheet, but paint what you need. As for the disappearing text, I think I might know the cause. However, following the rule for one problem per post, I suggest you to ask a new question. Please put there all the code needed to reproduce the issue and you will most certainly get help.

Comment: @Shun, if you want to make the border 2px tick, just set the pen of the painter before drawing the line: painter->setPen(QPen(Qt:black, 2));

Comment: Also I need custom widget item, so I use `listWidget.setItemWidget()` that does not cause the issue.

Comment: @Shun, so it is hard to understand what you have and what you need to do. Please post a new question and describe the problem in details. You can also like to this question, since the problems have something in common.